# Running multiple directories with PHPUnit 8.5

Tags: php, phpunit

If I want to run all test files within a directory I can run `phpunit tests/path/to/directory`. However if I run `phpunit tests/path/1 tests/path/2` where `1` and `2` are both directories containing test files, it complains that `Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'tests/path/1' could not be found`. How can I run both directories in one command?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to not invoke the PHPUnit test runner with path(s) on the CLI but configure the path(s) in your XML configuration file.